# Set the Display of a Related Entity in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to set and display a label for a related entity in MVC:

Related Domain Model:

```
[Table("Paises")]
public partial class Pais
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Ordem { get; set; }
}
```

Main Domain Model:

```
[Table("Entidades")]
public partial class Entidade
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Pais")]
    [Display(Name = "País")]
    public int Pais_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pais.Nome)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pais.Nome)
</div>
```

In the HTML Code I get the label "Nome" and I want to get the label "País".

How can I set the label correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this problem and make your application more robust in the face of change by simply using view-specific models instead of your domain models. Just make your view model a flattened version of your domain model and pull the related entity details up into the view model.  You can then decorate the view model properties as needed to get the output you desire.

```
public class EntidadeEditViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "País")]
    public string PaisNome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ordem")]
    public int? PaisOrdem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. In this project, I'm trying to simplify the application to avoid mapping the Model->VM or the complexity of an Automapper for example. Any ideia what is the problem in my case, or do you have a simple solution to map the Model->VM?

Comment: I would try putting the display attribute on the property in the related class. I honestly don't think it's much of a simplification to avoid the VM. AutoMapper is almost trivially easy to set up, especially if you set it up so the property names match as much as possible.